# Bitmap toString and back again

Tags: android, serialization, bitmap

in android I took a picture by the cam and returnded it to my activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == Constatnts.ANSWER_TO_LIFE_UNIVERSE_AND_EVERYTHING && data != null && data.getExtras() != null && data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {  
        Bitmap snapshot = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        String convert = InputOutput.bitmapToString(this, snapshot);
        Bitmap back = InputOutput.stringToBitmap(convert);
    }  
}
```

When I assign the Bitmap 'snapshot' to an imageview it loosk pretty good an works well. But when I assign the Bitmap 'back" to an imageview it does not change its view. So there must be something wrong in transformation. Here is my code for the tranformation:

```
public static Bitmap stringToBitmap(String bitmapString) {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(bitmapString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    return bitmap;
}

public static String bitmapToString(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    bitmap.recycle();
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stream.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    stream = null;
    String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    return strBase64;
}
```

Any suggestions what goes wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a code I used once to try this conversion, it should work:

```
public final static String bitmapToString(Bitmap in){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    in.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
}
public final static Bitmap stringToBitmap(String in){
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(in, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

You might want to add some `close()` calls to the streams though.